# How do I find a python interpreter installed within an application in linux?

Tags: python, linux, eclipse

I am trying to set up eclipse juno to write python scripts for an application that can use python scripts to automate tasks within the app. When creating a new PyDev project in eclipse I am supposed to select an interpreter. The interpreters installed in Linux are version 2.6 .

An application installed has a python script editor built in and uses python 3.3.0. Should there be a way for me to find the interpreter this application is using and reference it from eclipse?

I tried searching through the install directories and found a folder called python3.3 which contained scripts and libraries, but I couldn't find anything that looks like the interpreters I find installed in Linux, example "usr/bin/python2.6"

Comment: The embedded interpreter doesn't need the executable, just the .dll/.so file.

Comment: I see those in the application directory but they wont work for eclipse in place of an interpreter executable. Now I know that is a dead end, thanks.

Comment: Does "which python3" give your anything? If so, that's your interpreter. I believe you can install python3 with "sudo apt-get install python3".

It's possible the script editor has python 3.3.0 built in, that is, the python interpreter is part of the executable. In that case you won't find any interpreter floating around because it's part of the executable.